# Two divs, one above the other, both with 100% height of the screen

Tags: html, css

If I have one div with 100% height, how do I position another div with 100% height directly below the original div?

The first div is not positioned at the top of the page, but a bit further down after some scrolling.

```
<div id="section1" style="width: 930px;height: 1000px;position: relative;background-color: red;"></div>

<div id="section2" style="width: 930px;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 1000px;background-color: blue;"></div>

<div id="section3" style="width: 930px;height: 100%;position: absolute;background-color: green;"></div>
```

Comment: Please avoid using inline css...

Comment: Would be so nice if people helped with the actual question as much as they edit.

Comment: First of all you should help us help you. inline CSS makes your code unreadable and hard to work with, especially when it comes to CSS issues. read [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: It does, are you able to direct me on how to center it though? I use the text-align: center on the body tag, but it does nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/Lqz1x76w/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use css [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function:

```
#section3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(1000px + 100%); /* top of #section2 + it's height */ 
  width: 930px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqz1x76w/embedded/result/)

*Update:*

Center aligned [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqz1x76w/7/embedded/result)

css `calc()` browser support @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Glad to help.. please delete the comment below question... it'll only confuse other readers :p

Answer (score 1):

How about using a container div with absolute positioning to hold two absolute elements?

Like so:

<strike>**HTML**</strike>

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="lower"></div>
    <div class="upper"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: 600px;
}
.container div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Update**

Just use two regular div elements with `100vh` height - this means 100% of the viewport height.

```
<div class="lower"></div>
<div class="upper"></div>

div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.upper {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
.lower {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4x3k9j8r/3/

Comment: I edited my question to reflect what I actually meant, not underneath, but below. As in, user sees the first div with 100% height, then when you scroll down you see the second div with 100% height.

Comment: Sure, just use two relative divs with 100vh height.

Comment: This is close to what I want however, this just makes the upper div fill the remaining space, i need both the upper and lower div to fill the screen height separately.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, I see what you mean. Fiddle updated.